# Nestjs controller async problems

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise, nestjs

I am currently writing a finance-tracker app and have built a data import from a CSV file that checks if an entry is already in the database, if not adds a certain category to an entry and then saves it to the database.

After importing a CSV file, I want to output as a response to the Post Request: The number of imported entries as well as all entries for which no suitable category was found. Unfortunately, I fail because of the asynchronous approach of Nestjs. However, my response is output before the other functions are done. So that the first import is always “imports: 0” and “unsortedTransactions: []. ”

How can I wait in the controller for all functions to complete before returning a response?
TransactionController:

```
@Controller('transactions')
export class TransactionController {
  constructor(
    private transactionService: TransactionService,
    private labelService: LabelService,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './uploads/csv',
        filename: randomFilename,
      }),
    }),
  )
  public createTransactions(
    @Response() response,
    @UploadedFile() file,
    @Request() request,
  ) {
    let imports = 0;

    fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(file.path), {
      encoding: 'utf-8',
    })
      .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: false, delimiter: ';', skipRows: 1 }))
      .on('data', (data) => {
        const timestamp = new Date()
          .toISOString()
          .slice(0, 19)
          .replace('T', ' ');
        const amount = parseFloat(data[14].replace(',', '.'));
        const bankaccountId = request.body.bankaccount_id;
        const bookingDate = this.createDate(data[1]);
        const name = data[11].replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
        const usage = data[4].replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');

        this.transactionService
          .checkDuplicate(amount, name, usage, bookingDate)
          .then((entry) => {
            if (entry.length === 0) {
              this.sortLabel(data).then((label_id) => {
                const newTransaction = {
                  amount,
                  name,
                  usage,
                  label_id,
                  bankaccount_id: bankaccountId,
                  booking_date: bookingDate,
                  created_at: timestamp,
                  updated_at: timestamp,
                };

                this.transactionService.create(newTransaction);
                imports++;
              });
            }
          });
      });

    const unsortedTransactions = this.transactionService.getUnsorted();
    return response.send({ unsortedTransactions, imports });
  }

  private async sortLabel(transaction: Transaction): Promise<any> {
    let label_id = 1;
    const labels = await this.labelService.getAll();
    const name = transaction[11].replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    const usage = transaction[4].replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    labels.forEach((label) => {
      if (label.keywords != null) {
        const keywords = label.keywords.split(',');

        keywords.forEach((keyword) => {
          if (
            name.includes(keyword.toLowerCase()) ||
            usage.includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
          ) {
            label_id = label.id;
          }
        });
      }
    });

    return await label_id;
  }

  private createDate(date: string): string {
    const dateArray = date.split('.');

    return `20${dateArray[2]}-${dateArray[1]}-${dateArray[0]}`;
  }
}
```

Transaction Service:

```
export class TransactionService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Transaction)
    private readonly transactionRepository: Repository<Transaction>,
  ) {}

  public create(transaction): Promise<Transaction> {
    return this.transactionRepository.save(transaction);
  }

  public getAll(): Promise<Transaction[]> {
    return this.transactionRepository.find({
      relations: ['label_id', 'bankaccount_id'],
    });
  }

  public getUnsorted(): Promise<Transaction[]> {
    return this.transactionRepository.find({
      where: {
        label_id: 1,
      },
    });
  }

  public checkDuplicate(
    amount: number,
    name: string,
    usage: string,
    booking_date: string,
  ): Promise<Transaction[]> {
    return this.transactionRepository.find({
      where: {
        amount,
        name,
        usage,
        booking_date,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Too complicated,which DB are you using? If entry exists,findOne can check that(sequelize).

Comment: I'm using a mySQL Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take advantage of `async` / `await` functionality in js. You are returning promises from your service so this is easy.

Make the following changes

Add the async keyword to a function. (This allows you to `await` other functions inside)

```
  public createTransactions(
    @Response() response,
    @UploadedFile() file,
    @Request() request,
  ) async {....
```

```
  fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(file.path), {
      encoding: 'utf-8',
    })
      .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: false, delimiter: ';', skipRows: 1 }))
      .on('data', async (data) => {

        //... removed for brevity

        const checkDuplicateRes = await this.transactionService.checkDuplicate(
          amount,
          name,
          usage,
          bookingDate,
        );

        if (checkDuplicateRes.length === 0) {
          const labelId = await this.sortLabel(data);
          const newTransaction = {
            amount,
            name,
            usage,
            label_id: labelId,
            bankaccount_id: bankaccountId,
            booking_date: bookingDate,
            created_at: timestamp,
            updated_at: timestamp,
          };

          await this.transactionService.create(newTransaction);
          imports++;
        }
        const unsortedTransactions = await this.transactionService.getUnsorted();
        return response.send({ unsortedTransactions, imports });
      });

  }
```

Here we are basically replacing the `.then` syntax with the above. If you aren't familiar, i'd recommend reading up about it as it is much easier to follow than chaining `.then()`s

Comment: Hi James, thank you very much for your assistance. However, this produces the same output for me as before. The first time the CSV file is uploaded, { "unsortedTransactions": [], "imports": 0 } is returned again.

Comment: Hmm, I'm assuming your database is saving and getting records properly? I'd recommend checking the values in there. The fact that `imports: 0` still happens looks like your `(checkDuplicateRes.length === 0)` is failing. Which means that anything in that block won't run. You may want to investigate this function `this.transactionService.checkDuplicate(amount, name, usage, bookingDate)`. Since What is here should work in terms of (a)waiting for the async calls to finish.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. I tried it again without the checkDuplicate function. However, it doesn't work like that either, the data is imported correctly into the database, so entries are created. I think it's something nestjs specific that database operations are executed asynchronously and the response is returned from the controller.

Comment: You can definitely await the db reads / writes. Is everything inside the read stream callback? It's hard to tell but your response.send and statements must also be inside the callback `.on('data', (data) => {//here}` or they will be async to the readstream as well

Comment: Yes it's inside the the callback of the readstream. I created a fiddle with the whole controller: https://jsfiddle.net/fcumh218/1/

Comment: Taking a look at your jsFiddle. I've edited my answer with what you need to do. Your last two statements aren't inside the callback from the looks of it. So I've moved them up just below the `imports++` but outside that `if` statement. Try that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the problem is solved. In the after­­­­­tally logical.